# SplitViewController's master side sometimes is not rendered correctly when changing orientation in IOS 6.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, storyboard, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a tab bar controller that has some tabitems. Some of the tabitems are splitviewcontrollers. Sometimes, when I change orientation, the left side of the splitview controller does not render correctly, I have a black square in the bottom. By changing the orienation again, the problem is solved.

[image]

There is nothing special in my code. In the viewdidload I have:

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
self.splitViewController.delegate = self;
```

And one splitviewcontroller delegate method is handled trivially:

```
- (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc shouldHideViewController:   (UIViewController *)vc inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{
return NO;
}
```

I have nothing more, just some tableview on it with some cells on the detail side.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen such issue and the only workaround I came up with was to reset the size of the left side view controller's view and also it's navigation controller's view:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
    if (self.splitViewController) {
        viewHeight = ...
        navViewHeight = ...
        CGRect viewFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, viewHeight);
        self.view.frame = viewFrame;

        CGRect navControllerViewFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, navViewHeight);
        self.navigationController.view.frame = navControllerViewFrame;
    }
}
```

Where viewHeight and navViewHeight you can calculate from screen height depending on current orientation (which has already been set when didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation: is called). I guess these values should be equal for you as you hide the navigation bar.